# VSTACK in Excel: cell format linked to exact cell position, not data

Tags: excel, colors, formatting, vstack

I created a master sheet using vstack function which collect data from several other sheets. However, when I mark certain data with color fill or text color in master sheets, an unwanted effect seen: when new rows added in other sheets, it makes rows shift downwards in excel, which is of course completely normal, but the formatting (cell color fill) stays in the row. Text color formatting just disappears.
E.g. I have data in row 100 in master sheet. Cell A100 is filled with red color. When a row is added to on of the sheets, data shift to row 101, but color fill stays within cell A100.
Is there any way to avoid this? This almost led me to a fatal mistake...

I haven't tried anything to fix this because I have no idea what can be done.

Comment: Unless you can create a rule for conditional formatting to highlight the correct cell based on value, this is not something formula can do.  The formatting is tied to the cell.  The value returned by the spill of the formula is independent of the cell, so Excel cannot link the two.